# Combine range from multiple sheets into single column in order (top, bottom, left, right)

Tags: google-sheets

I have found some great formula's on this website but I can't figure out how to order my values from top to bottom and left to right. I have the following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(CONCATENATE({(Sheet1!A1:Z100&"-");(Sheet2!A1:Z100&"-")})))),"-"))
```

It does a great job at filing every value into a single column but it is reading left to right and it's driving me nuts seeing it out of my desired order! Is there a way to restructure this? I have found that the following formula keeps it in the order I want but I can't combine multiple strings with transpose.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z100&"-"))),"-"))
```

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CpMUo-XFBkILAMi7BPmwXS4p05kT20qhRrOHJJidrvM/edit?usp=sharing).

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

Result sheet

[image]

Comment: You have both `google-sheets` and `excel-formula` as tags. These are two very different applications. Please choose one and edit your post to reflect that change.

Comment: Updated. They are similar to me but that is because I came from Excel and have only begun learning Sheets syntax, and how it is very much different like you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header";QUERY({FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A:B));FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A:B))},"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null")})`